# jQuery Funtion Mouseenter and Mouseleave Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transforms

I am trying to make the element `.circle1` move back and forth with CSS transform from mouse hover on the "ring" element using jQuery. However, this is not working and would like some insight on what my error is.

```js
$("#ring").on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $(.circle1).css({
      "transform": "translateY(1000px)"
    });
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $(.circle1).css({
      "transform": "translateY(0px)"
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#ring {
  background-size: contain;
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}
.circle1 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>
  <img id="ring" src="New Assets/ring5.png" alt="">
</a>
<div class="circle1">
  <li class="products"><a href="#">Products</a>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Missing quotes around `$(".circle1")` <- typo

Comment: Open your browser console for insight to errors for starters. Would show you right away you have javasscript syntax error

Comment: Oh god, I just realized. Silliest mistake ever, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selector is not properly used for circle.

```
$("#ring").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
         $(".circle1").css({"transform":"translateY(1000px)"});
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(".circle1").css({"transform":"translateY(0px)"});
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Clumsy me.